# coreNLP significantly slowing down spark job`

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I'm attempting to make a spark job that does classification through cutting a document into sentences, and then lemmatizing each word in the sentence for logistic regression. However, I'm finding that stanford's annotation class is causing a SERIOUS bottleneck in my spark job (it's taking 20 minutes to process only 500k documents)

Here is the code I'm currently using for sentence parsing and classification

Sentence parsing:

```
def prepSentences(text: String): List[CoreMap] = {
    val mod = text.replace("Sr.", "Sr") // deals with an edge case
    val doc = new Annotation(mod)
    pipeHolder.get.annotate(doc)
    val sentences = doc.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation]).toList
    sentences
}
```

I then take each coremap and process the lemmas as follows

```
def coreMapToLemmas(map:CoreMap):Seq[String] = {
      map.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation]).par.foldLeft(Seq[String]())(
    (a, b) => {
        val lemma = b.get(classOf[LemmaAnnotation])
        if (!(stopWords.contains(b.lemma().toLowerCase) || puncWords.contains(b.originalText())))
      a :+ lemma.toLowerCase
    else a
  }
)
}
```

Perhaps there's a class that only involves some of the processing?

Comment: What annotators are you using? It looks like all you need is lemmas, which means all you should have to run is "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [CoreNLP's Shift Reduce parser implementation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#srparser).

A basic example (typing this without a compiler):

```
val p = new Properties()
p.put("annotators", "tokenize ssplit pos parse lemma sentiment")
// use Shift-Reduce Parser with beam search
// http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml
p.put("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.beam.ser.gz")
val corenlp = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)

val text = "text to annotate"
val annotation = new Annotation(text)
corenlp.annotate(text)
```

I work on a production system which uses CoreNLP in a Spark processing pipeline. Using the Shift Reduce parser with Beam search improved the parsing speed of my pipeline by a factor of 16 and reduced the amount of working memory required for parsing. The Shift Reduce parser is linear in runtime complexity, which is better than the standard lexicalized PCFG parser.

To use the shift reduce parser, you'll need the shift reduce models jar which you should put on your classpath (which you can download from CoreNLP's website separately).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've started looking into the SR parser and the neural network parser, and they both look like REALLY good paths to check out. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Taylor, I've been looking into shift reduce parsing and for some reason it's been running REALLY slow. I've even gone so far as to give the JVM 6G of memory so that the size of the model wouldn't be a limiting factor, but for some reason even when you don't account for the time taken to build the processor It's only processing 100 sentences per second (as opposed to 1000 sentence for PCFG). Is there any chance you could please let me know if there's something I'm doing wrong here? Thank you! http://pastebin.com/S0ZyN7Fp

Comment: I don't see anything immediately that would cause the SR parser in your code to perform more slowly. I'll try your code out here in a bit on some of my own data and see if I can replicate your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Taylor R! One thing to mention is that I'm doing my parsing one one document at a time (a document being 10 to 20 sentences) using a foreach loop (sentences.foreach(originalParser.parseSentence)), for your dataset are you using a large text corpus per "annotation" or a small one?

Comment: (also, the foreach loop isn't for the spark job, right now I'm just running a non-spark program to test different parser settings which can then be ported to spark once I've proven one to be faster)

Comment: Hi Taylor, just wanted to let you know that I also ported this to a different question. Please let me know if the code works ok on your data and thank you again for helping me on this! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356624/sentence-parsing-is-running-extremely-slowly